# JQuery/Javascript - Firefox crashes on simple task, no console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, crash

Firefox is crashing when executing this simple function while Chrome, Safari and IE do  not have any problem to execute this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if($('.fside_img').length>0) {
        gundeToggling(0,2000);
    }

});

function gundeToggling(prev,speed) {

    // 1. Choose a victim
    var victim = Math.floor(Math.random()*7); // number between 1 and 6

    // 2. Check if allowed or back to 1
    var alpha = $('#dn-a-'+victim);
    var beta = $('#dn-b-'+victim);

    var ctf_val = parseInt($('#ct_fones').val()); // Menge der sichtbaren prims
    var cts_val = parseInt($('#ct_sones').val()); // Menge der sichtbaren secs

    if(alpha.is(':visible') && ctf_val>2 && victim!=prev) {
        alpha.fadeOut(speed);
        beta.fadeIn(speed,function() {
            $('#ct_fones').val(ctf_val-1);
            $('#ct_sones').val(cts_val+1);
            gundeToggling(victim,speed);
        });
    } else if(beta.is(':visible') && cts_val>2 && victim!=prev) {
        beta.fadeOut(speed);
        alpha.fadeIn(speed,function() {
            $('#ct_fones').val(ctf_val+1);
            $('#ct_sones').val(cts_val-1);
            gundeToggling(victim,speed);
        });
    } else {
        gundeToggling(prev,speed);
    }
}
```

It is a function to fadeIn / fadeOut 6 Images by random order. I also tried to find the next images recursivley, but Firefox still crashes. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you please recreate this issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Did you try to narrow down the places that firefox can crash because of them?

Comment: May not matter, but `Math.floor(Math.random()*7)` should results in `0-6`, not `1-6`.

Comment: you build a recursion. maybe you forgot you breaking-condition... maybe you are running an a endless-loop...

Comment: I will try to narrow down this, but it will take some time.

Thx for the tip with random.

Comment: Yes I think it is an endless loop, but WHY?

Comment: Have you tried using setTimeout() when recursing? It looks like your function executes continuously and the browser might not be handling that well. setTimeout() will give some breathing room to update the UI.

Comment: I will try that and give you feedback later on that. But in all other Browsers the functions seems to execute only one per time, while firefox makes parallel calls.

Comment: inside your method gundeToggling you are everytime calling the same function again. there is no else-block which doesn't call it again.

Comment: Yes i know that there is no else block, because it should run constantly. But the second parameter is a callback function which is called on animation END, so with a timeout out 2000.

Comment: If you want to keep fading in/out with those 6 images, don't do that in a recursive manner. You can at least try `setTimeout(func,0)` to run it "asynchronously" so the function always quit, instead of keeping an infinite stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello thank you for your help, the tip with setTimeout was very useful for debugging, as I could avoid the crash.

But the real problem was the following:

The :visible Selector works in Firefox different than in all other Browsers. So jQuery in Firefox thinks, that visible content blocks (missing image) were invisible, which was responsible for an endless loop as more images were invisible as the script allowed. Solution:  Alt-Text for missing images :-P

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:
Try it in another browser (chrome, ie, opera, safari). 
Try to do lot of debug (put comments & alerst lot of place to see where can run and where not the whole js) 
Close every other tab.

Idea #2:
I had this problem also with a carousel, the fix was simple. Disable all extension and plugin in firefox. (Okay i had this problem only in the firefox, all other browser still work fine... )

Comment: I tried in all other browsers and it is working. I also tried with different firefox installations, as I got some feedback.

Comment: Very interesting. Maybe in the gungeToggling support / tickets / issues dont write this problem?

And still working on different OS with ff? (Example in virtual-bxed linux/macosx + firefox)